# Set theory identity

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that $(A\triangle B)\triangle (A\cap B) = A\cup B$ .

I tried and mostly went in circles. The idea is to use that 
$(A\triangle B)=(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)$ and also 
$A\setminus B = \bar A\cap B$ where $\bar A$ is absolute complement of A together with the De Morgan's laws . These are the few lines:

$(A\triangle B)\triangle (A\cap B)$ = $[(\bar A\cap B)\cup(\bar B\cap A)]\triangle(A\cap B)$ = ...

I would post my solution so far but I suck at LaTeX so it would take me too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, that's a good start!  Please do know that $A - B = A \cap \bar B$ rather than $\bar A \cap B$

Now:

$$(A\triangle B)\triangle (A\cap B) =$$

$$[(A- B)\cap(B-A)]\triangle (A\cap B) =$$

$$[(A\cap \bar B)\cup(B\cap \bar A)]\triangle(A\cap B)= $$

$$\big( [(A\cap \bar B)\cup(B\cap \bar A)]-(A\cap B)\big) \cup \big( (A\cap B)-[(A\cap \bar B)\cup(B\cap \bar A)]\big)=$$

$$\big( [(A\cap \bar B)\cup(B\cap \bar A)]\cap \overline{ (A\cap B)}\big) \cup \big( (A\cap B)\cap \overline{[(A\cap \bar B)\cup(B\cap \bar A)]}\big) = \text{ (DeMorgan)}$$

$$\big( [(A\cap \bar B)\cup(B\cap \bar A)]\cap (\bar A\cup \bar B)\big) \cup \big( (A\cap B)\cap \overline{(A\cap \bar B)}\cap \overline{(B\cap \bar A)]}\big) = \text{ (Distribution and DeMorgan)}$$

$$\big( [(A\cap \bar B)\cap (\bar A\cup \bar B)]\cup[(B\cap \bar A)\cap (\bar A\cup \bar B)]\big) \cup \big( (A\cap B)\cap (\bar A\cup B)\cap (\bar B\cup A)]\big) = \text{ (Absorption x 4)}$$

$$(A \cap \bar B) \cup(B\cap \bar A) \cup  (A\cap B) = \text{ (Adjacency)}$$

$$(A \cap \bar B) \cup B = \text{ (Reduction)}$$

$$A \cup B$$

Tedious ... but not hard.

To make this a little less tedious, please note that $\triangle$ is associative, and so:

$$(A \triangle B) \triangle (A \cap B) =$$

$$A \triangle (B \triangle (A \cap B)) =$$

$$A \triangle [(B - (A \cap B)) \cup ((A \cap B) - B)]=$$

$$A \triangle [(B \cap (A \cap B)^C) \cup ((A \cap B) \cap B^C)]=$$

$$A \triangle [(B \cap (A^C \cup B^C)) \cup (A \cap (B \cap B^C))]=$$

$$A \triangle [(B \cap A^C) \cup (B \cap B^C) \cup (A \cap \emptyset)]=$$

$$A \triangle [(B \cap A^C) \cup \emptyset \cup \emptyset)]=$$

$$A \triangle (B \cap A^C)=$$

$$(A - (B \cap A^C)) \cup ((B \cap A^C)-A)=$$

$$(A \cap (B \cap A^C)^C) \cup ((B \cap A^C) \cap A^C)= \text{ (Idempotence)}$$

$$(A \cap (B^C \cup A)) \cup (B \cap A^C)= \text{ (Absorption)}$$

$$A \cup (B \cap A^C)=\text{ (Reduction)}$$

$$A \cup B $$

... hmm. still tedious ....

Comment: I'm a little tired now so maybe i'm missing something but how did you get the last 3 lines?

Comment: @DreaDk $(B \cap A^C) \cap A^C = B \cap A^C$ by Idempotence ($A \cap A = A$); $A \cap (B^C \cap A) = A$ by Absorption ($A \cap (A \cup B) = A$; $A \cup (B \cap A^C) = A \cup B$ by Reduction

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was just me missing obvious things.

Comment: @DreaDk You're welcome! :)

Comment: @DreaDk P.S. I just added the steps for when using the original expression

Answer (score 2):

Rather than endless algebraic manipulations of expressions involving unions, intersections and complements, it would be far easier to use the definitions of set equality, intersection and union directly: that is, prove that for all $x$, you have
$$x \in (A \triangle B) \triangle (A \cap B) \quad \text{if and only if} \quad x \in A \cup B$$
I'll start you off:

> Suppose $x \in (A \triangle B) \triangle (A \cap B)$. Then by definition of $\triangle$, we have $x \in A \triangle B$ or $x \in A \cap B$, but not both.
>
> - If $x \in A \cap B$, then in particular $x \in A$, so $x \in A \cup B$ and you're done.
> - If $x \in A \triangle B$, then $x \in A$ or $x \in B$ (but not both); in any case, $x \in A \cup B$.
>
> In both cases, we've proved $x \in A \cup B$.

This proves that $(A \triangle B) \triangle (A \cup B) \subseteq A \cup B$.

You now need to prove the converse.

This method has the additional benefit of making the result more intuitive. What it's saying is that $x \in A \cup B$ if and only if either $x$ is in exactly one of $A$ or $B$, or $x \in A \cap B$, and moreover these latter cases are mutually exclusive.

Comment: 'endless algebraic manipulations' seems a bit exaggerated :)  But yes, it's tedious, so this is a good alternative!

Comment: @Bram28: Reading my answer back, it sounds a little bit like I was trying to insult your answer - that wasn't my intention! In any case, I do tend to prefer double-containment proofs of set theoretic identities (except very basic ones), because they're closer to the definitions. (I have pedagogical reasons for preferring this approach too, but I won't go into that here.)

Comment: Oh, I didn't take it that way at all :)  And yes, it's often more conceptually intuitive than pure algebra, I totally agree!